# Drawing lines on a page at absolute locations

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to build a lined form (A4) as per [image: WHO Medical Form]

However I'm finding it hard to get my head around the coordinate system tikz uses...
Right now I'm finding the lines are going the wrong directions..

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=5.2cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,verbose,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path (2cm,27cm) node (p2) {};
\path (2cm,1cm) node (p1) {};
\draw (p1) to (p2); 

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I did manage to hammer something into shape, but I think the answer below might be more sensible.. particularly as I noticed my A4 page was apparently 30cm tall!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,verbose,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\node [shift={(-21 cm,-30cm)}]  at (current page.north east)
{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

    \path (2cm,1cm) node (p1) {};
    \path (2cm,30cm) node (p2) {};
    \path (0,1cm) node (p3) {};
    \path (21cm,1cm) node (p4) {};
    \path (20cm,1cm) node (p5) {};
    \path (20cm,30cm) node (p6) {};
    \path (2cm,26cm) node (p7) {};
    \path (20cm,26cm) node (p8) {};
    \path (20cm,15cm) node (p9) {};
    \path (21cm,15cm) node (p10) {};
    \path (11cm,26cm) node (p11) {};
    \path (11cm,30cm) node (p12) {};
    \path (2cm,27cm) node (p13) {};
    \path (11cm,27cm) node (p14) {};
    \path (2cm,30cm) node (p15) {};

    \draw (p1.center) to (p2.center);   
    \draw (p3.center) to (p4.center);   
    \draw (p5.center) to (p6.center);   
    \draw (p7.center) to (p8.center);
    \draw (p9.center) to (p10.center);
    \draw (p11.center) to (p12.center);
    \draw (p13.center) to (p14.center);

%draw hole punches to ISO838
    \draw (1.2cm,11) circle (0.6cm);
    \draw (1.2cm,19) circle (0.6cm);

    \draw (2.5cm,26.5cm) node[anchor=west,draw=none]{\Large{Poisons Case Record}};
    \draw (20.5cm,14.5cm) node[anchor=west, rotate=270 ,draw=none]{\Large{Poisons Case Record}};

    %if we have the aust coloured system then this one is it
    %\draw[blue] (20cm,15cm)rectangle (21cm,30cm);

    \end{tikzpicture}

};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try by positioning relative to the corners of the page. Here's an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=5.2cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,verbose,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

  \coordinate (BL) at (current page.south west); % bottom left
  \coordinate (TR) at (current page.north east); % top right

  \fill[yellow!20] (BL) rectangle ++(2, \paperheight) node[pos = 0.5, rotate = 90, black]{Some text};

  \fill[blue!20] (TR) rectangle ++(-3, -\paperheight) node[pos = 0.5, rotate = 90, black]{Some text};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good work. I upvote your answer.+1

Comment: This makes more sense than the way I did it! :) - I'll add the way I did it the the question though

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion using a layer page style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newlength\topboxheight
\setlength\topboxheight{6\baselineskip}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,bottom=1cm,top=\dimexpr1cm + \topboxheight\relax,verbose,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer}

\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{form}{form.lines,form.right.lower,form.text.top.left,form.text.top.right}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  textarea,
  addvoffset=-\topboxheight,
  addheight=\topboxheight,
  mode=picture,
  contents={%
    \put(\LenToUnit{-\layerxoffset},0){\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\paperwidth}}}%
    \putUL{\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\layerwidth+\layerxoffset\relax}}}%
    \putLL{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\layerheight+\layeryoffset\relax}}}%
    \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
    \put(\LenToUnit{\layerwidth},\LenToUnit{.5\layerheight}){%
      \line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\layerwidth-\layerxoffset}}}%
    \put(\LenToUnit{.5\layerwidth},\LenToUnit{\layerheight}){%
      \line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\topboxheight}}}
    \put(0,\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\layerheight-\topboxheight\relax}){%
      \line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}
    \put(\LenToUnit{-.8cm},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\layerheight-19cm\relax}){%
       \circle{\LenToUnit{1.2cm}}}
    \put(\LenToUnit{-.8cm},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\layerheight-11cm\relax}){%
       \circle{\LenToUnit{1.2cm}}}
  }
]{form.lines}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  rightmargin,
  voffset=.5\paperheight,
  height=.5\paperheight,
  contents=\hfill\rotatebox{270}{\Large Poissons Case Record}\hfill
]{form.right.lower}
\makeatletter
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  addvoffset=-\topboxheight,
  height=\topboxheight,
  contents={%
    \parbox[t][\layerheight]{.5\layerwidth}{%
      \begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
        Hospital name\hfill\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image}\\[.5\baselineskip]
        Patient:\enskip\@patientname\\
        \@otherdetails
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
  }
]{form.text.top.left}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=form.text.top.left,
  addhoffset=.5\textwidth,
  contents={%
    \parbox[t][\layerheight]{.5\layerwidth}{%
      \begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
        Medical record number:\enskip\@medicalrecordnumber\rule{0pt}{2\baselineskip}\\[.5\baselineskip]
        Ward:\enskip\@ward
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
  }
]{form.text.top.right}

\newcommand\@patientname{}
\newcommand\patientname[1]{\edef\@patientname{#1}}
\newcommand\@otherdetails{}
\newcommand\otherdetails[1]{\edef\@otherdetails{#1}}
\newcommand\@medicalrecordnumber{}
\newcommand\medicalrecordnumber[1]{\edef\@medicalrecordnumber{#1}}
\newcommand\@ward{}
\newcommand\ward[1]{\edef\@ward{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}%dummy text
\begin{document}
\patientname{Bimbo Bull}
\otherdetails{Some text as other information.}
\medicalrecordnumber{123456789}
\ward{WWW}
\thispagestyle{form}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer as I don't need to faff around with text boxes